# Proof about coprime polynomials.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory

[image]

I(f,g) in this case is equal to

af+bg : a,b${\in}$K[x]

I know I have to draw a contradiction first and show that if 1$\notin$I(f,g) then f and g are not relatively prime, but I'm confused how to show this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)?  This is true for polynomials over a field, because there is a Euclidean algorithm to compute gcd's there.